# Surprising Limit of Expected Value of Difference

Tags: probability, limits, recreational-mathematics

Let $S_n = \{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \}$. For every non-empty subset $S$ of $S_n$, denote $$\Delta_S = \max S - \min S.$$

What is the expected value of $\Delta_S$ ?

We can compute this as follows. We can form every nonempty subset by first picking a maximum value $k$, then a minimum value $j$ such that $j \le k$. For the calculation, we can ignore the cases where $j = k$ since $\Delta_S = 0$ in that case. Thus, the expected value of $\Delta_S$ is

$$\frac{1}{2^n - 1} \sum_{k = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^{k - 1} (k - j) 2^{k - j - 1}. $$

Evaluating this sum, we get

$$\mathbb{E}[\Delta_S] = \frac{(n - 3)2^n + (n + 3)}{2^n - 1}.$$

While trying to understand the behavior of this quantity, I noticed that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n - \mathbb{E}[\Delta_S] = 3.$$

This result is very unintuitive to me. Can anyone provide an insight to why such a beautiful and surprising fact holds?

Comment: Each random variable $\min S$ and $n-\max S$ is "almost" geometric with parameter $1/2$ in the sense that they are distributed as $G$ conditionally on $G\leqslant n$ where $P(G=k)=1/2^k$ for every $k\geqslant1$. Thus, $n-E(\Delta_S)=E(\min S)+E(n-\max S)=2E(G\mid G\leqslant n)$ converges to $2E(G)=4$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: *Typo: What I wrote applies to $\min S$ and $n+1-\max S$ (so that these two random variables have the same support $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$), not  to $\min S$ and $n-\max S$, hence $n-E(\Delta_S)=2E(G\mid G\leqslant n)-1$ for every $n$ and indeed the limit is $2E(G)-1=3$.

Answer (score 2):

$\Delta$ only depends on the extremal values. By counting these 'extremal probabilites', we have
 $P(\Delta=n-1) = P(1\in S, n\in S)=1/4$,
 $P(\Delta=n-2)=P(1\notin S,2\in S, n\in S) +  P(1\in S, n-1\in S, n\notin S)=2 \times 2^{-3}$, etc... so
 $P(\Delta=n-k)= k \times 2^{-(k+1)}$ for $k<n/2$. The average of $n-\Delta$ converges as $n\rightarrow \infty$ to 
  $$ \sum_{k\geq 1} k^2 2^{-(k+1)} =3 .$$
(Thanks to Did for checking)

Comment: Hmmm... $ \sum\limits_{k\geq 1} k^2 2^{-k} =6$.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are saying that the terms $k < n/2$ add increasingly negligible value as $n \rightarrow \infty$ so we can ignore them? How do we know that?

Comment: The convergence is fast. The last term go rapidly to zero (it is of the order of the one just before). You could try to write down the detailed expression for the last term(s) but it does not influence much upon the limit

Answer (score 2):

Toss a coin to decide whether $1$ is included, then another to decide whether $2$ is included, then another to decide whether $3$ is included, etc.

What is the average value of the first one included?  I.e., on average, how many times do you toss the coin in order to get one "head"?  Since there are two equally probable outcomes, the answer is $2$.

Similarly with $n$, then $n-1$, then $n-2$, then $n-3$, etc.: The average is $n-1$.

So $(n-1) -2 = n-3$.

(This is of course about the limit, not about the exact value for finite $n$.  If one cannot toss the coin more than $n$ times, then the average gets smaller, with this complication: What if the random set has no elements?  What is the value of the minimum then?  Or the maximum?  If it has just one element, then the difference -- the **range**, as it is usually called -- is $0$.)

Comment: This neglects the fact that one can toss at most $n$ coins hence the end result is never exactly $n-3$.

Comment: @Did : True --- I intended this only to suggest what the _limit_ is, not the exact value for finite $n$. $\qquad$

Comment: @Did : ok, I've added a parenthetical remark at the end.  Do you have any ideas about what to do when the size of the set is $0$?  Do we just use the fact that the limiting probability of that is $0$ so we can neglect it? Or maybe deal only with a conditional distribution given that that does not happen? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Just to make sure I understand what you are trying to say: EV of delta = EV(Max) - EV(Min). We can approximate EV(Max) by tossing a coin starting from n and working down to 1. On average, we get heads from two tosses so approximately, EV(Max) is n - 1 and similarly, EV(Min) = 2.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal : Correct. $\qquad$